# can express.static find your mounting file

Tags: node.js, express

I have seen some code online and was wondering how the index.HTML was getting rendered when we are not using any app.get()

the public file structure follow like this:

css(folder),
js(folder),
chat.html,
index.html,

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

When an incoming request matches a directory name that `express.static()` is configured for, then `express.static()` will look for an `index.html` file in that directory and, if found, will serve it.

You can see this feature mentioned [here in the doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), in the `index` option you can pass `express.static()` that allows you to specify the name of the `index.html` file to look for (default value is `index.html`) or you can set it to `false` to disable the feature.

So, in your code example, with this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

an incoming http request for `/` will look for `public/index.html` and, if found, will serve it automatically.  Similarly a request for `/foo` will look first for `/public/foo` and if that is present and is a directory, then it will look for `public/foo/index.html` and, if found, will serve it.

Comment: @mehCoder - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the stackoverflow community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.